# Consulta a duas tabelas no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Minha situação é a seguinte: tenho varias tabelas que possuem algumas informações em comum, como UNIDADE.

Numa destas tabelas tenho todas as minhas unidades e preciso verificar se esta mesma UNIDADE tambem existe em outra tabela, e caso exista, exibir as informações desta outra tabela.

Ex:

Tabela_A

```
unid  -  info
100   -  20
101   -  15
102   -  40
103   -  35
```

Tabela_B

```
Unid  -  info
101   -  25
103   -  40
```

o que desejo exibir:

```
100 - 20
101 - 25
102 - 40
103 - 40
```

Todas as pesquisas as unidades serão individuais, vou estar consultando somente 1 unidade por vez, logo consultado a unidade 103, preciso somente da informação 40.

---

**EDIT:**

Código Atual:

```
Select cgc, 
       unidade, 
       MAX(velocidade) as vel , 
       circuito, 
       Rot, 
       ip_wan, 
       ip_lan, 
       loopback0, 
       loopback21, 
       loopback22 

From circuitos_rede_2 

Where cgc=457 Not Exists (Select cgc From circuitos_permanentes ) 

Union 

Select cgc, 
       unidade, 
       veloc 

From circuitos_permanentes
```

Comment: Felipe, o que você já pesquisou até aqui? Leia [ask] e [tour] e reflita se sua pergunta está de acordo.

Comment: Amigo... Se alguma resposta te ajudou, assinale "aceite" na melhor resposta e votando em todas que te ajudaram. Assim você garante que quem escreveu a resposta receba algo em troca, além de tornar o site mais limpo e útil para todo mundo.

Answer (score 7):

Tenta isso, ve se funciona.

```
(SELECT unid, info FROM TabelaUM 
 WHERE unid NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Unid FROM TabelaDOIS))
UNION
(SELECT unid, info FROM TabelaDOIS)
```

---

Editando para se enquadrar na tua necessidade

```
SELECT cgc, unidade, MAX(velocidade) AS vel , 
       circuito, Rot, ip_wan, ip_lan, loopback0, 
       loopback21, loopback22

FROM circuitos_rede_2 
WHERE cgc=457 NOT EXISTS (select cgc from circuitos_permanentes ) 

UNION 

SELECT cgc, unidade, veloc AS vel, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
FROM circuitos_permanentes
```

Comment: Valeu @LucasMotta pela dica, porem ao tentar aplicar a solução passada por você, esta me dando erro de syntax. Desculpe, mas sou bem novato, e por isso pode parecer "for dummies".

Comment: Cola teu código aqui, ou edita tua resposta e cola o código no final

Comment: o codigo que estou utilizando é exatamente este:

SELECT cgc, unidade, MAX(velocidade) AS vel , circuito, Rot, ip_wan, ip_lan, loopback0, loopback21, loopback22  FROM `circuitos_rede_2` 
WHERE cgc=457 NOT EXISTS (select cgc from `circuitos_permanentes` )
UNION
select cgc, unidade, veloc from `circuitos_permanentes`

Comment: Se não estou enganado, você precisa ter a mesma quantidade de coluna em ambas.
Editei minha resposta, da uma olhada

Answer (score 2):

uma das formas de se fazer essa consulta é utilizando UNION entre os SELECTs.

Abaixo segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT Info FROM Tabela_A
WHERE UId = 103

UNION

SELECT Info FROM Tabela_B
WHERE UId = 103
```

Caso precise ordernar ou agrupar os resultados basta adicionar no último select a instrução *ORDER BY* ou *GROUP BY*

```
SELECT Info FROM Tabela_A
WHERE UId = 103

UNION

SELECT Info FROM Tabela_B
WHERE UId = 103
GROUP BY 1
```

Obs: o número 1 do *GROUP BY* representa a primeira coluna do select

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Usar `Group By` sem nenhuma operação, o máximo que ele pode nesse exemplo é usar o `Order By`

Comment: @LucasMotta não entendi o que você quis dizer, mas nesse select é possível sim utilizar o GROUP BY para agrupar os valores repetidos dos 2 selects

Comment: Sim, tens razão

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja um join.
segue um exemplo no sqlserver, mas a query do join pode ser usada em vários SGBDs.

```
create table REDE1 (COD INT, CAMPO_A VARCHAR(10) NULL, CAMPO_B VARCHAR(10),CAMPO_C VARCHAR(10),CAMPO_D VARCHAR(10),
    CONSTRAINT PK_REDE1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (COD)
)
GO

create table REDE2 (COD INT, CAMPO_E VARCHAR(10) NULL, CAMPO_F VARCHAR(10)
    CONSTRAINT PK_REDE2 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (COD)
)
GO

create table REDE4 (COD INT, CAMPO_G VARCHAR(10) NULL, CAMPO_H VARCHAR(10),CAMPO_I VARCHAR(10)
    CONSTRAINT PK_REDE4 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (COD)
)
GO

create table REDE5 (COD INT, CAMPO_J VARCHAR(10) NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_REDE5 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (COD)
)
GO

INSERT INTO REDE1 VALUES
(1,'CAMPO A', 'CAMPO B', 'CAMPO_C', 'CAMPO D'),
(2,'LINHA 2', 'LINHA 2B', 'LINHA 2C', 'LINHA 2D'),
(3,'LINHA 3A', 'LINHA 3B', 'LINHA 3C', 'LINHA 3D'),
(4,'LINHA 4A', 'LINHA 4B', 'LINHA 4C', 'LINHA 4D'),
(5,'LINHA 5A', 'LINHA 5B', 'LINHA 5C', 'LINHA 5D'),
(6,'LINHA 6A', 'LINHA 6B', 'LINHA 6C', 'LINHA 6D')
GO

INSERT INTO REDE2 VALUES
(3,'CAMPO E', 'CAMPO F'),
(5,'CAMPO E', 'CAMPO F'),
(6,'CAMPO E', 'CAMPO F')
GO

INSERT INTO REDE4 VALUES
(1,'CAMPO G', 'CAMPO H', 'CAMPO_I'),
(6,'LINHA G', 'LINHA 2H', 'LINHA 2I')
GO

INSERT INTO REDE5 VALUES
(6,'LINHA 5J')
GO

SELECT R1.*, R2.CAMPO_E, R2.CAMPO_F, R4.CAMPO_G, R4.CAMPO_H, R4.CAMPO_I, R5.CAMPO_J 
FROM REDE1 R1
JOIN REDE2 R2 ON R1.COD = R2.COD
JOIN REDE4 R4 ON R2.COD = R4.COD
JOIN REDE5 R5 ON R4.COD = R5.COD
```